# Joining attribute data from one layer to another layer in QGIS 2.12.2-Lyon

Tags: qgis, vector, attribute-table, vector-grid, attribute-joins

I have a polygon vector layer that I am trying to join its attributes to a point vector layer. The problem is that the polygon layer consists of grids that are numbered 1-150 (ID) and I am trying to join these grid ID's to over 1000 yield points that fall within the grid (some points actually do not fall within the grids). Every time I perform the join (in properties), the attributes come up as 'NULL'. 
This is basically what I am trying to achieve:

.[image: This is basically what I am trying to achieve]

Comment: Are the data have a same projection?

Comment: Yes. I have tried both options of same and different projections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are in the same projection You can use spatial join from Vector -> Data Management Tool -> Join Attributes by location. Try to use "Take attributes of first located feature" as shown below.

[image]

Comment: The only problem with the 'Join Attributes by location' is that it only allows me to obtain the Mean, min max etc. I would like to obtain the specific value of each point and not a grouped recording of all of them.

Comment: I updated my answer. choose the first option as shown in the image.

Comment: This has worked!

Comment: Glad it worked.